# Playing sound in Python using Psychopy and or PyGame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, spyder, psychopy

I have installed all dependencies (such as pyo) for PsychoPy sound and get no errors when attempting to play a sound file (.wav).

On my Windows 10 PC at work Spyder plays the file without issue. On my Windows 7 Pro PC at home this happens:

[image]

No information about what is going wrong is given. It simply sits there doing nothing. Any ideas what is happening?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

Something similar happens when trying to play a sound file using pygame. However, it simply runs the code and starts a new kernel without the file being played or an error report. Could this be a problem with Pyo or a driver issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually gave up on the pyo library and successfully managed to play sound in PsychoPy using PyGame by doing the following BEFORE calling `sound` from psychopy:

```
from psychopy import prefs
prefs.general['audioLib'] = ['pygame']
```

...

```
sound.Sound(value = soundfile)
```

I've found Pyo to be a nightmare when using Windows 7 Pro. Hopefully this work around with PyGame will come in useful.